# android - views with same width placed horizontaly without filling all screen

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to create menu layout where I can place buttons in two colums with same width.

I don't want to stretch buttons to fill all screen (unless there are long lables).

I want all buttons to have same width - the width of the button with the longest label.

I'm trying two vertical linear layouts inside one horizontal linear layout.

All solutions that I found suggest to use same layout_weight for vertical linear layouts and layout_width=fill_parent for horizontal layout which is forcing buttons to occupy entire screen width.

Is there any common solution for my problem?


This is what I expect - https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2751770/android-layout1.PNG

This is how common solution looks like - https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2751770/android-layout2.PNG


And here is code which I'm using as a common solution:

```
<LinearLayout style="@style/menuLayout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent" 
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:baselineAligned="false">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button style="@style/menuButton"
                android:text="Title 1"/>
        <Button style="@style/menuButton"
                android:text="Title 2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button style="@style/menuButton"
                android:text="Title 3"/>
        <Button style="@style/menuButton"
                android:text="Long title 4"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Styles:

```
<style name="menuLayout">
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
</style>
<style name="menuButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Actually can you make it clear what exactly is your problem? and what is happening right now? and give a screenshot and paste your code here so that we can improve it

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the width in the style "menu_layout" and also again in the second line of your code.Remove one of them. And try using `android:weightSum="1"` in the parent `LinearLayout` and then `android:layout_weight="0.5"` in each `LinearLayout`.